# Why does const vector<const pair<...>> give an 'cannot be overloaded' error?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

I have this simple code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void foo(const std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int> > & networks) {
  for (auto p : networks) {
  }
}

void bla(const std::vector<const std::pair<std::string, int> > & networks) {
  for (auto p : networks) {
  }
}
```

This produces an error in `bla()`:

```
mrvn@frosties:~% g++ -O2 -W -Wall -g -std=gnu++17 -c bla.cc
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/c++allocator.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:61,
                 from bla.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of ‘struct __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >’:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/allocator.h:92:11:   required from ‘class std::allocator<const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >’
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:79:14:   required from ‘struct std::_Vector_base<const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::allocator<const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >::_Vector_impl’
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:164:20:   required from ‘struct std::_Vector_base<const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>, std::allocator<const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> > >’
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:214:11:   required from ‘class std::vector<const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >’
bla.cc:10:17:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/ext/new_allocator.h:93:7: error: ‘const _Tp* __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::address(__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_reference) const [with _Tp = const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_pointer = const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>*; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::const_reference = const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&]’ cannot be overloaded
       address(const_reference __x) const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
       ^
/usr/include/c++/5/ext/new_allocator.h:89:7: error: with ‘_Tp* __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::address(__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::reference) const [with _Tp = const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::pointer = const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>*; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::reference = const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&]’
       address(reference __x) const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
       ^
```

My Question is: WHY?

Note: used g++ 5.4 and 7.3.

Comment: i am almost sure that `vector` doesnt work for `const` T until C++11, though as I understand the requirements in C++17, this shouldnt be an issue

Comment: Perhaps the error message in MSVC is a bit more descriptive: *"The C++ Standard forbids containers of const elements because allocator<const T> is ill-formed."*

Comment: @Blaze so since C++17 this restriction is encoded in the Erasable concept?

Comment: @Blaze I think SMVC is wrong, because `std::vector<const int, std::allocator<int>>`is rejected by all compilers.

Comment: Could be, I don't know enough of the underlying topics. Either way the error persists if I set it to "ISO C++17" or "ISO C++ Latest Draft"

Comment: @Blaze MSVC is correct, it is illformed, the template must be cv-unqualified.

Comment: How does a mutable vector of const values make sense?

Comment: The interface for `std::vector` guaranties that `const std::vector<T>` can't be used to modify it's elements. For all intents and purposes the `T`s might as well be considered implicitly `const`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Only in the context of their use/access, not in the context of their existence. They _can't_ be implicitly `const` in that sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I could gather so far from the standard and documentation:

`std::vector` is an [allocator-aware](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/AllocatorAwareContainer) container.

As per C++17 (final working draft N4659)

> 20.5.3.5 Allocator requirements [`[allocator.requirements]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/allocator.requirements#tab:desc.var.def)
>
> Table 30 says:
>
> T, U, C       any **cv-unqualified** object type (6.9)

For `std::vector` it is also required that element type is a complete type and meets the requirements of Erasable.

From [`[container.requirements.general]/15`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/container.requirements.general#15) we have:

> Given an allocator type A and given a container type X having a
>   value_type identical to T and an allocator_- type identical to
>   `allocator_traits<A>::rebind_alloc<T>` and given an lvalue `m` of type `A`,
>   a pointer `p` of type `T*`, an expression `v` of type (possibly const) `T`,
>   and an rvalue `rv` of type `T`, the following terms are defined.
>   ...
>   (15.6) — T is Erasable from X means that the following expression is
>   well-formed: `allocator_traits<A>::destroy(m, p)`

Since element type in the question is `const` qualified, it fails to meet the requirements.

Answer (score 4):

There is a requirement for having non const values in a vector:

> /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8.2.0/../../../../include/c++/8.2.0/bits/stl_vector.h:351:7: error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'is_same, allocator >, int> >::type, const pair, allocator >, int> >::value' "std::vector must have a non-const, non-volatile value_type"

Let's start from the vector requirements down to the allocator issue. The type in `vector` must support this:

> The requirements that are imposed on the elements depend on the actual operations performed on the container. Generally, it is required that element type meets the requirements of Erasable, but many member functions impose stricter requirements. This container (but not its members) can be instantiated with an incomplete element type if the allocator satisfies the allocator completeness requirements.

So we need to have something that can be `Erasable` and where we can do:

```
std::allocator_traits<A>::destroy(m, p);
```

with `m` the allocator and `p` the type that we want to destroy. Fair enough. What more do we need? Erasable needs an Allocator:

> Specifies that an object of the type can be destroyed by a given Allocator.

, which in turns requires `T` to be [cv-unqualified](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator):

> T, a cv-unqualified object type

So you can have a `std::pair<const string, int>`, but not a `const std::pair<std::string, int>`.

In that regard, MSVC message is clearer, as it directly tells you that it's the allocator that is ill-formed.

Comment: Can you point to the requirement? I read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) but i dont really understand the Erasable concept

Comment: I see the Erasable requirement but nothing should get erased in this code (nor should anything get allocated). So I'm not sure how that applies in this case. But if you find the part in the standard defining that "std::vector must have a non-const, non-volatile value_type" I will accept this as answere.

Comment: Ersable -> Allocator -> T has to be cv-unqualified.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow It does not matter that you are not erasing anything. The element type has to abide by _Erasable_, with the properties that entails. It's as simple as that!

Comment: If that's the case then I would expect the compiler to fail in the function declaration already. And not later when the vector is used. In my case the .h file should give an error already.

Comment: The prototype doesn't check anything at this stage, it's perfectly fine.

Comment: Then I don't really understand why you find this answer less desirable than the other one despite being more detailed.

Comment: and yet, `std::vector<const int, std::allocator<int>>` is rejected by compilers.